# Webscraping doesnt return the expected html?

Tags: c#, html, web, web-scraping

Been working on a shopping app for a while(which is working), and are now looking to expand the features, however my understanding of website element/file hierakis etc is lackluster to say the least!

Im reading this url: [https://minetilbud.dk/tilbudsaviser/aldi/1?id={E2193C06-1136-4ED7-9B66-693C3EB175FF}](https://minetilbud.dk/tilbudsaviser/aldi/1?id=%7BE2193C06-1136-4ED7-9B66-693C3EB175FF%7D)

What im looking for is the text part that includes "30,- per kg". However when i read the html programmicly im getting a ton of text that doesnt contain this particular wanted text.

Sorry for my poor explained question but im not really sure what im looking for here, could the text im looking for be hidden? 
in another file? 
another url?

Any tips that can help me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The text can easily be fetched for instance by Ajax calls (JavaScript),

Comment: What library are you using to parse the HTML?  What code have you written?  Your question is basically "I've done something and it doesn't work, please tell me why".  Please include some detail

Comment: a lot of websites are dynamic, and get a lot of data *after* the html has been loaded (with JavaScript, mainly)

Comment: Thanks Poul, im on my way to bed now but ill give it a try first thing tomorrow!

Neil: Im using the StreamReader(C#) to get the base HTML of a url, then im sorting and cleaning it with classes of my own. So far it has worked fine, but now id like to get more details that seems to not be on the base HTML. Have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Pac0 Alright, that sounds like it could be the problem, ill look into that first thing in the morning, thanks!

Comment: @user1094935, actually what I meant was, that the site uses Ajax calls to fetch the html. WebClient/HttpClient or what you use does not automatically call JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like each clickable product has a product id that can be used to make an api request with to get the info in structured JSON. The page loads these id's with that second script tag towards the top of the html via a url that starts with something like this:

https://cdn.ipaper.io/iPaper/Papers/0996f096-0e32-4fd4-b62b-f40e59e490ea/Enrichments/v1/

If you scrape this url then do a get against that you should get back json that contains the product id's. Then you would want to store those product id's and then do more get requests with those product id's in this format.

https://minetilbud.dk/api/rest/product/%7BD1E5927C-6EDD-4F3C-A925-1141077F3D96%7D

So
https://minetilbud.dk/api/rest/product/%7{product id}%7D

You can see all this in the chrome dev tools or fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else stated, the reason you can't find the details is because it's fetching the data using ajax after the page has loaded. The URL fetched is...

```
https://minetilbud.dk/api/rest/product/%7BE2193C06-1136-4ED7-9B66-693C3EB175FF%7D
```

Which returns...

```
{  
   "advert":{  
      "id":"{E2193C06-1136-4ED7-9B66-693C3EB175FF}",
      "title":"Peanuts",
      "description":"",
      "imageUrl":"https://img2minetilbud.azureedge.net/cloud/prod/MediaStorage/0/8/08B2BEFC5D7D42DEB3AA47CED86DFFD7/28_28_2_.jpg?crop=699,31,1109,814",
      "price":"6,-",
      "pricePercentage":"",
      "pricePerUnit":"",
      "priceVolume":"30,- per kg",
      "categoryMainTitle":"Snacknødder",
      "tradeLabels":[  

      ],
      "validFromFormatted":"5/10",
      "validToFormatted":"11/10",
      "validtext":"Gyldig t.o.m tor 11/10",
      "videoId":null,
      "videoType":null,
      "videoCoverImage":null,
      "fullAdvertUrl":"/tilbudsaviser/aldi/1/side/28",
      "duplicates":[  
         {  
            "id":"e2193c06-1136-4ed7-9b66-693c3eb175ff",
            "title":"Peanuts",
            "price":"6,-"
         }
      ],
      "relatedAdvertsUrl":"/Tilbudssoegning?qw=Snacknødder",
      "headCategoryTitle":"Dagligvarer",
      "categoryTitle":"Snacknødder",
      "brand":"Joe's",
      "categoryVariantTitles":"Peanuts",
      "keywords":"",
      "isMinimumPrice":false,
      "advertType":"Advert",
      "externalLinks":[  

      ]
   },
   "customer":{  
      "name":"ALDI",
      "headerImageUrl":"https://minetilbud2.azureedge.net/-/media/Images/Blurs/aldi.jpg",
      "headerTextColor":"#FFFFFF",
      "primaryColor":"#1f3480",
      "secondaryColor":"#111f60",
      "circleLogo":"https://minetilbud2.azureedge.net/-/media/Images/Runde-logoer/aldi.png",
      "catalogs":"/tilbudsaviser/aldi",
      "openingHours":"/tilbudsaviser/aldi/aabningstider",
      "linkText":"Køb varen online"
   },
   "dictionary":{  
      "adverts":"s tilbudsaviser",
      "advertsLinkV2":"Tilbudsaviser",
      "chooseAdvert":"Vælg",
      "openingHours":"Åbningstider",
      "shareOffer":"Del tilbud",
      "relatedOffers":"Lignende tilbud",
      "goToShop":"Gå til webshop",
      "readAdvert":"Læs tilbudsavisen",
      "videoText":"Se [[BRAND]]s video",
      "shareOnFacebook":"Del på Facebook",
      "tellAFriend":"Tip en ven",
      "savePercentage":"Spar",
      "from":"Fra"
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello Aydin, can i ask what software or method you used to extract those data in that json format?